# Help Factoring Quadrinomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I know factoring questions are a dime a dozen but I can't seem to get this one.

$-2x^3+2x^2+32x+40$
Factor to obtain the following equation:
$-2(x-5)(x+2)^2$

Do I have to use division (I'd prefer not to)?  The way the question is worded, it seems I should just be able to pull factors out.  This is the farthest I could make it:
$-2(x^3-x^2-16x-20)$
$-2[x^2(x-1)-4(4x+5)]$
$-2[(x^2-4)(x-1)(4x+5)]$

Comment: Your second step is unhelpful and your third is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Henry.  I was trying to factor by grouping.  Where did I err?

Comment: $x^2(x-1)$ and $4(4x+5)$ do not have a common factor

Comment: Ooohhh, I see.  That's what happens when you're trying to remember everything without understanding why you're doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we know a factor, we can divide without dividing.

Start from $-2x^3+2x^2+32x+40$, and use the factor $x+2$.

We can rewrite as $(-2x^3-4x^2)+6x^2+32x+40$, and then as 
$(-2x^3-4x^2)+(6x^2+12x)+20x+40$.

So our expression is equal to $-2x^2(x+2)+6x(x+2)+20(x+2)$ and  we can pull out the $x+2$. We get $(x+2)(-2x^2+6x+20)$.

But there is no good reason to avoid polynomial division!

**Remark:** If you are calculus-minded, let $P(x)$ be our polynomial. Write the **Taylor expansion** of $P(x)$ about $a=-2$, that is, in powers of $x+2$. Instead of division, we will use differentiation.

Comment: I only avoid division because I don't like the trial and error of finding the factor...  I guess it's just inevitable.

Comment: I'm still confused by it telling me to factor to find $2(x-5)(x+2)^2$

Comment: Division by a *monic* polynomial (lead coefficient $1$, like $x+2$ or $x^2-17x+3$), involves no trial and error.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you were saying, but that's what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the roots by the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  Once you have pulled out the common $2$, the rational roots are factors of $20$, of which there are only $12$ (counting plus and minus).  So just try them until you find one that works.